# Drawing a systematic sample

Tags: sampling, systematic

Please clarify the following question:
If two independent systematic samples of size 
four each from a population of 36 units have y-values of a characteristic y as:

24,26,22,28 and 27, 25, 23, 29 
respectively, find the unbiased estimate of mean and variance.

My confusion: from several theories on systematic sampling, I read about this random interval k=N/n. In this case, k=36/4= 9. In the above samples nowhere I find a gap of 9 instead a gap of 2 is noticed. how could this happen? I can in no way relate the theory I read to the above given samples.

Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here: 
You are mistaken in thinking that any patterns in the $y$ variable must somehow match the order (or index) of observations in the list. The two sets of number need have nothing to do with one another.  Let $i = 1 \ldots 36$ indicate the order in which each observation is listed in the frame. A systematic sample of size 4 begins by taking a random start between 1 and $k = 36/4 = 9$, then every 9-th observation after that.  However, the values of the $y$'s can be **anything** in general.

In some situations, the  $y$'s *can* be related to list order, as when observations are listed in date order and the $y$'s are dates.   However I don't see any kind of relation in your data. The gaps between adjacent observations in the first sample are +2, -4, +6.  In the second sample they are -2, -2, +6. Remember that "adjacent" in one of the systematic samples means "nine observations apart" in the original list.